# How can I change Blender's Zoom View to include the Alt key?

Tags: camera

Hello Blenderstackexchange-onians. I come from a Maya/Unity background and have been following various tutorials to mess with my viewport settings. I have things almost exactly how I want them, but I am stumped on adding the last setting.

What I am trying to do: Have my viewport zoom in and out while scrolling my mouse wheel while also holding down the alt key. Like this
https://gyazo.com/e7d49b96c35ec9a337e3573aae1390d5
except I want it to do this while I am holding down ALT.

What is currently happening: While ALT is held down and my mouse wheel is scrolled, it scrubs my timeline like this https://gyazo.com/73cb2a8b92c9aa42cf36d1c72daeb488

What I have tried: Adding these in User Preferences https://gyazo.com/c197bd312f767ae373733e5e155a5041

...I am assuming either I am doing the hotkey adding incorrectly or the animation timeline scrubbing is overriding my attempts at using the alt key while zooming.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to zoom using <kbd>Alt</kbd> and **holding** middle mouse button:

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> to open *User Preferences*
- Go to *Input* and find "Zoom"
- In the *3D View* section, find "Zoom View" and change *Ctrl Middle Mouse* to *Alt Middle Mouse*

[image]

---

If you also want to **zoom by holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> while scrolling the wheel**:

- Find "Zoom View" item with "Wheel In" / "Out" and add Alt to the shortcut
- Disable "Frame Offset" shortcut

[image]

Personally, I prefer to getting used to Blender's defaults if possible, as it often fit's the different workflow better.